# Process without writing output to console

Tags: c#, php, linux, mono

I have a PHP script , it executes my program, and my program starts  another process. But problem is, the PHP stock in executing for every writing to console output... I tested screen with -A -m -d parameters, but it didnot turn on process(program running ok, but process not started). Can I  not write output to console with C#? Or how to ignore the PHP and continue with scripts?

Better thanx

Comment: It is a little hard to understand your question, so can you please ask it again? Try to split it up into a few paragraphs, and explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Redirect the console output to /dev/null ? i.e. call your_program by `your_program > /dev/null` command

Comment: Sergey: Thanx, function correctly :) Please, close question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.IO.Stream.Null` to do that:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Stream.Null));
```